# SQLite Copy Table Content from one Table to another Table and Update

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, sql-insert, upsert

I have two SQLite files, each of them has one table and the same table design. One Column is set as Primary Key. I want to copy all data from `ItemsB` into `ItemsA`. All data should be updated. The ItemsB Table is the newer one.

I've tried:

```
ATTACH DATABASE ItemsB AS ItemsB;
INSERT INTO ItemsA.PMItem (ItemID,VarID,Name1) SELECT ItemID,VarID,Name1 FROM ItemsB.PMItem;
```

Obviously this can't work due the Primary Key (which is the column VarID).

Then I tried it with ON CONFLICT:

```
ON CONFLICT (VarID) DO UPDATE SET Name1=excluded.Name1
```

But this won't work either.

Example Table:

```
CREATE TABLE PMItem (
    ItemID INTEGER,
    VarID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Name1  TEXT
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UPSERT for "INSERT INTO tab SELECT \* FROM another\_tab"](/q/60981306/90527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `WHERE` clause with an always `true` condition, to overcome [the ambiguity](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) that is raised when `ON CONFLICT` is used after a `SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO PMItem (ItemID,VarID,Name1) 
SELECT ItemID,VarID,Name1 
FROM ItemsB.PMItem
WHERE 1
ON CONFLICT(VarID) DO UPDATE 
SET Name1 = EXCLUDED.Name1;
```

Comment: Aw that does the trick. Thanks! But I also found out, if I want to upgrade all columns, I also can use: `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ItemsA.PMItem SELECT * FROM ItemsB.PMItem;`
Now I have two solutions. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim `INSERT OR REPLACE` first deletes the conflicting row and then inserts the new row. This does not guarantee 100% that the inserted row will have the same VarID (which is auto-incremented since it is defined as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) as the deleted row.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But I don't use auto-increment on this primary key. At least I don't need a primary key but a unique key. Should I prefer using a unique key instead of primary key, when I am not using auto-increment?

Comment: @Tim when you define a column as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` then it is automatically treated by SQLite as an autoincremented column (to be precise it is an alias of the system column `rowid` which is autoincremented: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html). The tables in both databases have defined VarID as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`. If their actual values are not important and all you care about is that they are unique then fine, you don't need to change anything. My previous comment was meant to inform you about the difference of the statements `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE...` and `INSERT ... OR REPLACE...`